# What are the discrete and continuous hyper-parameters for KNN?

Tags: machine-learning, knn

I have this table

It says "Example classifiers in Scikit-Learn and their hyper-parameters.
Generally, hyper-parameters can be (a) discrete, e.g., number of
neighbors in kNN, or (b) continuous. e.g., the value of penalty in logistic
regression."

[image]

as you can see, KNN has 3 hyper-param.

2 discrete & 1 continuous
OK,

I know that K in KNN is one hyper-parameter?

So What are the other discrete and continuous hyper-param they are talking about?

Comment: Not sure about the continuous parameter (table source?), but apart from the number of neighbors `k`,  kNN has at least one more discrete parameter, the choice of the metric used - see the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier.html#sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer

I think there is mistake in that research

as the hyper-param are 2 continuous and 1 discrete

hyper-param

1- N neighbors (continuous)

2- Weights (cont)

3- Leaf Size (discrete)